# YouTube Authentication for a Deployed Website

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

When I deploy my application on Render.com, I add (`https://my_application_name.onrender.com/`) to the redirect URI, but Google Auth throws an error and gives an example of using

> "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback".

How am I supposed to authenticate my deployed application?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.   Your app is sending that redirect URI your to NOT supposed to send localhost as a redirect uri. Fix your app / code and google will stop telling you your doing it wrong.